# How to make protection aganist webspam

Tags: nginx, spam

I have a website on express and nginx server. Some one, dunno who and why, make spam requests to server. He asked wrong url's, sometimes urls that is real. And it never downloading content of the page. I can see this in my debug logs. Its looks like this:

```
GET /upload/resize_cache/iblock/ccf/600_500_1/ccfcdaaf1d5fe9369730f87af4cd1a1c.jpg 404 386.291 ms - 12514
GET /upload/iblock/4d3/4d3cb14cef960ea3ba225a417ac2d346.jpg 404 416.699 ms - 12422
GET /upload/iblock/546/54618496bf5cd184d6fb7274279a92a7.jpg 404 354.640 ms - 12422
GET /article/codepen-io-dobavyl-vozmozhnost-yspolzovanyia-shablonov 200 408.688 ms - 17421
GET /upload/resize_cache/iblock/b7f/600_500_1/b7f2644ef4e8d4463dc4e5805fc2cc82.jpg 404 144.151 ms - 12514
GET /running_auto/Audi/audi-a1-hatchback/ 404 133.696 ms - 12350
GET /article/funktsyonalnoe-programmyrovanye-v-js-chast-4 200 461.214 ms - 29747
GET /Volkswagen/Jetta/trade-in-form/ 404 387.641 ms - 12330
GET /upload/iblock/728/728ec19fa81415b11f00ee97261b3cc3.jpg 404 292.099 ms - 12422
GET / 200 312.443 ms - 56568
```

What i can do with requests that didnt take content, just asked for pages? That isnt such problem, but i have weak server and it cant handle to much this usles requests.

Answer (score 0):

A client can request whatever it likes, it is up to the server to provide a suitable response for the request received.

If the request is for an unknown resource simply return a 404 as soon as possible. Try not to create instances of objects, connect to databases etc until after you have asserted the request is valid.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a CDN, you could give a try to [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com)  and later just in case use the [WAF](https://cloudflare.com/waf).

From the [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-tcp/) side what you could do is to whitelist [CloudFlare's IP's](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) so that only CloudFlare hits your site, check this post: https://erichelgeson.github.io/blog/2014/01/18/whitelisting-cloudflare-in-nginx/

This may help to prevent your site going down from undesired requests.